# Возможно ли наложить водяной знак на изображение, загружаемое через форму на сайт?

Tags: drupal, изображения, php, yii

Конкретно нужна реализация на `PHP`. Или подскажите варианты и альтернативы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function watermark($sourcefile, $watermarkfile) {

#
# $sourcefile = Filename of the picture to be watermarked.
# $watermarkfile = Filename of the 24-bit PNG watermark file.
#

//Get the resource ids of the pictures
$watermarkfile_id = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkfile);

imageAlphaBlending($watermarkfile_id, false);
imageSaveAlpha($watermarkfile_id, true);

$fileType = strtolower(substr($sourcefile, strlen($sourcefile)-3));

switch($fileType) {
    case('gif'):
        $sourcefile_id = imagecreatefromgif($sourcefile);
        break;

    case('png'):
        $sourcefile_id = imagecreatefrompng($sourcefile);
        break;

    default:
        $sourcefile_id = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourcefile);
}

//Get the sizes of both pix   
$sourcefile_width=imageSX($sourcefile_id);
$sourcefile_height=imageSY($sourcefile_id);
$watermarkfile_width=imageSX($watermarkfile_id);
$watermarkfile_height=imageSY($watermarkfile_id);

$dest_x = ( $sourcefile_width / 2 ) - ( $watermarkfile_width / 2 );
$dest_y = ( $sourcefile_height / 2 ) - ( $watermarkfile_height / 2 );

// if a gif, we have to upsample it to a truecolor image
if($fileType == 'gif') {
    // create an empty truecolor container
    $tempimage = imagecreatetruecolor($sourcefile_width,
                                                                        $sourcefile_height);

    // copy the 8-bit gif into the truecolor image
    imagecopy($tempimage, $sourcefile_id, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                        $sourcefile_width, $sourcefile_height);

    // copy the source_id int
    $sourcefile_id = $tempimage;
}

imagecopy($sourcefile_id, $watermarkfile_id, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0,
                    $watermarkfile_width, $watermarkfile_height);

//Create a jpeg out of the modified picture
switch($fileType) {

    // remember we don't need gif any more, so we use only png or jpeg.
    // See the upsaple code immediately above to see how we handle gifs
    case('png'):
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        imagepng ($sourcefile_id);
        break;

    default:
        header("Content-type: image/jpg");
        imagejpeg ($sourcefile_id);
}

imagedestroy($sourcefile_id);
imagedestroy($watermarkfile_id);
}
```

PS. [пруфлинк](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#53100)